# R replace the column name by the dataframe name with a loop

Tags: r, rename

I am very new to programming with R, but I am trying to replace the column name by the dataframe name with a for loop. I have 25 dataframes with cryptocurrency time series data.

```
ls(pattern="USD")
[1] "ADA.USD"   "BCH.USD"   "BNB.USD"   "BTC.USD"   "BTG.USD"   "DASH.USD"  "DOGE.USD"  "EOS.USD"   "ETC.USD"   "ETH.USD"   "IOT.USD"
[12] "LINK.USD"  "LTC.USD"   "NEO.USD"   "OMG.USD"   "QTUM.USD"  "TRX.USD"   "USDT.USD"  "WAVES.USD" "XEM.USD"   "XLM.USD"   "XMR.USD"
[23] "XRP.USD"   "ZEC.USD"   "ZRX.USD"
```

Every object is a dataframe which stands for a cryptocurrency expressed in USD. And every dataframe has 2 clomuns: Date and Close (Closing price).
For example: the dataframe "BTC.USD" stands for Bitcoin in USD:

```
head(BTC.USD)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
Date       Close
1 2015-12-31  430.
2 2016-01-01  434.
3 2016-01-02  434.
4 2016-01-03  431.
5 2016-01-04  433.
```

Now I want to replace the name of the second column ("Close") by the name of the dataframe ("BTC.USD")

For this case I used the following code:

```
colnames(BTC.USD)[2] <-deparse(substitute(BTC.USD))
```

And this code works as I imagined:

```
> head(BTC.USD)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Date       BTC.USD
1 2015-12-31    430.
2 2016-01-01    434.
3 2016-01-02    434.
```

Now I am trying to create a loop to change the second column name for all 25 dataframes of cryptocurrency data:

```
df_list <- ls(pattern="USD")
  for(i in df_list){
  aux <- get(i)
  (colnames(aux)[2] =df_list)
  assign(i,aux)
}
```

But the code does not work as I thought. Can someone help me figure out what step I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` to assign the names, i.e.

```
Map(function(x, y) {names(x)[2] <- y; x}, l2, names(l2))
#$`a`
#  v1 a
#1  3 8
#2  5 6
#3  2 7
#4  1 5
#5  4 4

#$b
#  v1  b
#1  9 47
#2 18 48
#3 17  6
#4  5 25
#5 13 12
```

**DATA**

```
dput(l2)
list(a = structure(list(v1 = c(3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L), v2 = c(8L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
)), b = structure(list(v1 = c(9L, 18L, 17L, 5L, 13L), v2 = c(47L, 
48L, 6L, 25L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)))
```